# Capstone Disassembler to Extract OpCode from Malware and Benign Executables in C++

Tags: c++, disassemblers, executable

The project that I am trying to develop has as a vital component, specifically a machine learning based malware detection system. The way in which I decided to teach the detection system in order to distinguish between malware and benign files is by feeding it the mnemonics that will be extracted from the executables.

I came across two disassemblers, namely, capstone and LLVM-MC. I tried to search about how to extract the opcode but I did not manage to extract them. If it is possible, I would like to even use IDA, but still I do not know how to write such a script to use it in C++.

Could you please help me with a script in which it will take as input a path to an executable and outputs a text file in which all the data about that certain executable is extracted, and then I will just tidy up that file for removing everything but the mnemonics and their arguments?